# Clicking a date on datepicker displays an custom error for valueMissing

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I've made a from and a form validator. Two of the fields contain the jquery date picker. The problem is, that when the date in the datepicker is selected, the error message appears stating that the field must not be empty (triggered by `valueMissing`). I have to click the field again for the error message to be removed.

Javascript should remove the error if:

- on`change` happens (since the user has to click on the datepicker outside the input field I guess it doesn't trigger)
- on`blur` happens (which doesn't trigger the removal of the error.)
- on`focus` happens (which does remove the error, but I have to click the field again which kind of sucks.)

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8nzd3fks/1/), but I can't seem to get the datepicker on it to function. Sorry for that :(

If I can provide any additional data, please let me know.

*Edit* I took a different approach and tried to add a function to my datepicker which would remove the error. But it didn't work. If anyone has any ideas how to make it work, I would be very grateful. But to be fair, I would prefer to know why the error is being output anyway. Thank you.

```
//added function to datepicker
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    $("#arrivalDate").datepicker({
        minDate: 'dateToday',
        dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
        onSelect: function (date) {       
            var newDate = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
            if (newDate) { // Not null
                newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate() + 1);
            }
            $("#departureDate").datepicker('option', 'minDate', newDate);
            clearDate();
        }
    });
    $("#departureDate").datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'
    });
    
});


const e_arrDate = document.getElementById("e_arrDate");
const e_depDate = document.getElementById("e_depDate");

function clearDate(){
    setTimeout(function (){
        e_depDate.textContent = "";
        e_arrDate.textContent = "";
    },1 );
}
```

```
<form>
  <label for ="arrivalDate">Date of arrival:<span class="asterx">*</span></label>
    <div>
      <input type="text" id="datepicker" name="datepicker" required placeholder="Select a date of arrival." pattern="[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{4}">
      <div class="error" id="e_arrDate"></div>
    </div>
  <label for="name_field">Name:<span class="asterx">*</span></label>
    <div>
      <input type="text" id="name_field" name="name_field" required placeholder="Enter your Name"  pattern="[A-Za-z]{2,15}" autofocus />
      <div class="error" id="e_name_field"></div>
    </div>
  <label for="surname">Surname:<span class="asterx">*</span></label>
    <div>
      <input type="text" id="surname" name="surname" required placeholder="Please enter your Surname" pattern="[A-Za-z]{2,15}" />
      <div class="error" id="e_surname"></div>
    </div>
</form>
```

```
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll("input");
inputs.forEach(function(input){

    const e_space = input.closest("div").querySelector(".error");

    input.addEventListener("focus", function () {
        if(input.classList.contains("input-red")){
            input.classList.remove("input-red");
            input.classList.remove("b-r");
        }
    })

        //does not remove the error message
    input.addEventListener("change", function (){
        if(input.matches('[id="datepicker"]'){
            input.classList.remove("input-red");
            input.classList.remove("b-r");
        }
        if (input.validity.valueMissing === false && input.validity.patternMismatch === false) {
            e_space.textContent = "";
        }
    })

    input.addEventListener("blur", function (){

        //pattern mismatch - text
        if(input.matches('[type="text"]')){
            if(input.validity.patternMismatch){
                if(e_space){
                    e_space.textContent = "This field can only contain letters from a-z.";
                    input.classList.add("b-r");
                }
                input.classList.add("input-red");
            }
        }
        
        //pattern mismatch - datepicker
        if(input.matches('[id="datepicker"]')){
            if(input.validity.patternMismatch){
                if(e_space){
                    e_space.textContent = "Please select a date from the field.";
                    input.classList.add("b-r");
                }
                input.classList.add("input-red");
            }
        }

        //empty
        input.value = input.value.trim();
        if(input.validity.valueMissing){
            if(e_space){
                e_space.textContent = "This field must not be empty.";
                input.classList.add("b-r");
            }
            input.classList.add("input-red");
        }

        if (input.validity.valueMissing === false && input.validity.patternMismatch === false) {
            e_space.textContent = "";
            input.classList.remove("b-r");
        }

    })
})

/* in a different js file */
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
    minDate: 'dateToday',
    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you click on *datepicker input* then datepicker plugin gets open so the datepicker input loses focus that's why it doesn't work . A simply solution would be using `.focus()` to make input again focusable and to get rid of error messages .

***Demo Code*** :

```js
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll("input");
inputs.forEach(function(input) {

  const e_space = input.closest("div").querySelector(".error");

  input.addEventListener("focus", function() {
    if (input.classList.contains("input-red")) {
      input.classList.remove("input-red");
      input.classList.remove("b-r");
    }
  })

  //does not remove the error message
  input.addEventListener("change", function() {
    if (input.matches('[id="datepicker"]')) {
      input.classList.remove("input-red");
      input.classList.remove("b-r");
    }
    if (input.validity.valueMissing === false && input.validity.patternMismatch === false) {
      e_space.textContent = "";
    }
  })

  input.addEventListener("blur", function() {

    //pattern mismatch - text
    if (input.matches('[type="text"]')) {
      if (input.validity.patternMismatch) {
        if (e_space) {
          e_space.textContent = "This field can only contain letters from a-z.";
          input.classList.add("b-r");
        }
        input.classList.add("input-red");
      }
    }

    //pattern mismatch - datepicker
    if (input.matches('[id="datepicker"]')) {

      if (input.validity.patternMismatch) {
        if (e_space) {
          e_space.textContent = "Please select a date from the field.";
          input.classList.add("b-r");
        }
        input.classList.add("input-red");
      }
    }

    //empty
    input.value = input.value.trim();
    if (input.validity.valueMissing) {
      console.log("validate for ..")
      if (e_space) {
        console.log("validate for empty")
        e_space.textContent = "This field must not be empty.";
        input.classList.add("b-r");
      }
      input.classList.add("input-red");
    }

    if (input.validity.valueMissing === false && input.validity.patternMismatch === false) {
      e_space.textContent = "";
      input.classList.remove("b-r");
      console.log("All welll")
    }

  })
})
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
  minDate: 'dateToday',
  dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
  onSelect: function(date) {
    var newDate = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
    if (newDate) { // Not null
      newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate() + 1);
    }
    $("#departureDate").datepicker('option', 'minDate', newDate);
    document.getElementById("datepicker").focus(); //use this because input loses focus
    console.log("Inside datepicker")
  }
});
```

```css
.c-r {
  color: red;
}

.c-g {
  color: green;
}

.b-r {
  border-color: red;
}

.input-red {
  background-color: #cc3b3b;
}

.error {
  color: red;
  font-size: smaller;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />

<form>
  <label for="arrivalDate">Date of arrival:<span class="asterx">*</span></label>
  <div>
    <input type="text" id="datepicker" name="datepicker" required placeholder="Select a date of arrival." pattern="[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{4}">
    <div class="error" id="e_arrDate"></div>
  </div>
</form>
```